# NSDK Skip instruction?

Tags: c#

Sorry in advance for the inappropriate tag (this is more a NSDK issue than a C# issue, but NSDK tag wasn't existing, and I couldn't create it so I had to choose one...)

I'm currently writting a webservice using C#.
My goal is to reproduce what a NSDK code is doing.

Everything is going ok so far but one thing.
I have absolutely no clue about what the skip instruction is doing.

Here is an exemple of an instruction

```
if skip SomeString <> ''
```

I know this is testing if someString is empty or not, but the "skip" makes me wonder what it does.

The main goal of my webservice is to create a file, and to send it to a printer after a writing phase and I need to be vary careful with spaces or backlines and stuff so if someone could explain this to me, I'd gladly appreciate!

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my Answer.

skip instruction is removing spaces at the beginning and the end of the string.

For instance :

VALUE$ = "  key "
There is 2 spaces before and 1 space after the value.

length(VALUE$) gives 6 (the 3 spaces + the three letters)
length(skip VALUE$) gives 3 (only the three letters)

So skip VALUE$ equals "key", and not "  key "